# How to make a modeless dialog always on top within the app

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I have a modeless popup dialog in my app. I want to make it topmost only within the app it belongs to, not always topmost on the desktop.

I have tried to set the first parameter to wndTopMost, but this way the dialog will remain on top on the desktop, which is very bad user experience.

I have also tried wndNoTopMost with SWP_NOZORDER parameter, but this only put the dialog in front when its displayed. If I move another dialog/window to the dialog location, the dialog will be buried under the new dialog/window.

I am currently using the SetWindowPos in the OnInitDialog();

```
   SetWindowPos(&wndNoTopMost
    , myRect.left
    , myRect.top
    , myRect.Width()
    , myRect.Height()
    , SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOCOPYBITS | SWP_NOZORDER
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes `HWND_TOPMOST` is a *very* bad user experience, so I will commend you for not taking the easy way out and trying to flip this switch.

The key to getting a dialog to appear on top of other windows is setting its *owner*. (Note that [in Win32, an owner is distinct from a parent window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx), although the terms are often confusing.) All dialogs have an owner, and dialogs always stay on top of their owner.

So when you create the modeless dialog (e.g. using the `CreateDialog` function), make sure to specify the handle to your application's main window as its owner. Confusingly, the parameter is named `hwndParent`, but it actually specifies the owner window.

Comment: This does not address the question: If an application has two (or more) modeless dialogs (owned by the same window), the last dialog the user interacted with will be in front of sibling dialogs. Thinking this through, though, a solution would lead to a situation, where a user can hide the dialog they are interacting with behind another dialog. This sounds like a questionable design decision in itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So basically I want to make this popup dialog a topmost notification within the app. I have tried to set the app's MainFrame as the owner window when I create this modeless dialog. However my app is a MDI, when another window is activated, it can still overlay my notification popup dialog.

Comment: Setting window owner has consequences if dialog is in another thread, it implicitly attaches the input queues of the threads which those windows belong to.